# Python C bindings Py_InitModule issue

Tags: python, binding, compilation

This latest programming project of mine has pushed some boundaries I haven't crossed before; mainly, I've begun doing some serious C programming. Stack Overflow's users have been exceptionally helpful so far, so I will draw on your knowledge again. I want to write some bindings C function bindings (drawing pixels to the screen using SDL) for Python, and I am, once again, stuck on a compiler error.

This line:

```
Py_InitModule3("ezpix", ezpix_methods, "ezpix extension");
```

Gives me this error:

```
POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '_Py_InitModule3'.
POLINK: fatal error: 1 unresolved external(s).
```

I find it odd that it says _Py_InitModule3 when I put Py_InitModule3, is the syntax parser adding in an underscore or something? I'm using Pelles C for Windows, and the rest of my code (including the scarier looking bits) have compiled just fine.

Comment: You do know that [pygame](http://pygame.org) is an SDL binding, right?

Comment: Really? Huh. It goes WAY too slow for what I'm doing. I looked at the pygame source and there is a bunch of garbage for setting pixels that must REALLY bog it down. What I'm trying seems like it should work MUCH faster, since I'll just be passing arrays of pixel values to the drawing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the mangled name of the function, which isn't found in the library because it's a macro from [modsupport.h](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d38509db3616/Include/modsupport.h#l124):

```
#define Py_InitModule3(name, methods, doc) \
    Py_InitModule4(name, methods, doc, (PyObject *)NULL, \
                   PYTHON_API_VERSION)
```

modsupport.h gets included by Python.h.

Comment: What does this mean and how do I fix it?